# Hackerrank repeated string, hign value not printing in c++

Tags: c++

The below given code is not working for high value (eg: 51574523448, 1000000000000, etc) even after using long long and giving some different different values but is properly working for low values.

Can anyone explain what is the problem and how to solve it. (Sorry for weak english).

```
int repeatedString(string s, long n) {

    long count = 0;
    int secondCount = 0;
    long num;
    int length = s.length();
    double remainder;
    num = (long) n / (length);
    remainder = n % (length);

    for(int i=0; i < length; i++) {
        if(s[i]=='a') {
            count++;
            if(i < remainder)
             secondCount++;
        }
    }
    count = count*num + secondCount;

    return count;
}
```

Comment: `Not working`, care to tell us what it is supposed to when it is working? Also telling us what it does now would be helpful. This is basic information that you should provide without being asked.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this program on your platform:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<long>::max() << '\n';
}
```

The number it prints is the maximum value a `long` can store. I get `2147483647`, which is much less than 51574523448. You will likely need to use a larger data type, such as `long long`.